# не получается обратиться к методу класса из-за ошибки E0245 C++

Tags: c++, классы, методы

при попытке написания дурака на cpp столкнулся с проблемой вызова метода из класса, а именно ошибка:

> E0245  нестатическая ссылка не член должна указываться относительно заданного объекта

игроку нужно указать размер колоды в переменную *size_deck* и через метод *_set_size_deck*
записать это значение в класс *Deck*

```
//.cpp файл

#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

#include"Deck.h"
#include"Headers.h"

namespace durak {
    void StartDurak()
    {
        std::cout << "choice how cards in deck 24/36/52" << std::endl;

        int size_deck;
        std::cin >> size_deck;

        Deck::_set_size_deck(size_deck);// << ошибка возникает здесь 
    }
}
```

```
//файл .h с классом 

#pragma once

class Deck
{
public:

    void _set_size_deck(int _size_deck)// << пытаюсь вызвать этот метод 
    {
        _size_deck = size_deck;
    }

protected:

private:
    int** deck = new int*;
    int size_deck; // << чтобы записать значение сюда 
};
```

есть еще файл с main() но там настройки консоли и вызывается функция durak::StartDurak()

буду очень благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись с именем класса и `::` допустима только для функций, объявленных как `static`, то есть для всего класса.

```
Deck::_set_size_deck(size_deck);
```

У вас же функция

```
void _set_size_deck(int _size_deck)
```

объявлена не как статическоая, а значит, должна вызываться *для конкретного объекта*.

Здесь

```
void StartDurak()
{
    std::cout << "choice how cards in deck 24/36/52" << std::endl;

    int size_deck;
    std::cin >> size_deck;

    Deck::_set_size_deck(size_deck);// << ошибка возникает здесь 
}
```

у вас нет никакого объекта, поэтому непонятно, что вы хотите и как исправить ваш код. У какого конкретно объекта вы хотите изменить значение члена?

И еще, вы точно скопировали код? `_size_deck = size_deck;`? тут вы присваиваете аргументу член класса, а не наоборот. не думаю, что так и надо.

Кстати, начинать имена с подчеркивания не следует, есть определенные ограничения, но лучше вообще не иметь такой привычки.